# VB.NET - Push data to a TextArea inside a webpage

Tags: vb.net, winforms, internet-explorer, browser, textarea

I'm currently developing a WinForm VB.NET app.

I want to add a function who will pass text from a TextBox in my Form to a specific TextArea in a webpage opened within Internet Explorer.

I **DO NOT** want to use a WebBrowser. I know it's possible this way but in my case, I need to use Internet Explorer.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT : This app is a program of macro who works with the Windows's Clipboard. At work we have the WEB software BMC Remedy. Most of the time, the field "Resolution" contains the same text. In order to save some time, when a macro (ex: CTRL + NumPad1) is pushed, the program put the text "linked" to this macro (ex: "Reboot the computer!") into the clipboard. And then we can do a CTRL+V into the TextArea in the BMC Remedy page. But it would be even better for the users if the text would put itself into the TextArea without a CTRL+V.

Comment: and what type of browser is Internet Explorer?

Comment: By WebBrowser, I mean the WebBrowser component in Visual Studio. Sorry.

Comment: What will happen once the text appears in the browser? Maybe expand the post to include the full logic of what you are trying to do. Very few reasons to subclass an entire browser for inputting text into a field, but there may be a reason.

Comment: could you AutoHotKey straight into the remedy textbox http://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: I took a look at AutoHotKey. I think it could be a solution. Unfortunately, at work only a couple of persons can install stuff on their computer.

Comment: Is it possible to get a specific tab in IE by name? At this point, I think I could just put the tab foremost and do some "Tab" to the TextArea where I want to put text into it. Then a little paste to the TextArea.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Much easier than getting tab by name for IE

Answer (score 0):

COMs you need to add to your project ;

- Microsoft Internet Controls
- Microsoft HTML Object Library

Maybe it's not the best way to do it but it's working. I'm not the author or this code.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14161/

Have fun!

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim SWs As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
    Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    For Each IE In SWs
        If IE.Name = "Internet Explorer" Then
            If IE.LocationName <> "" And IE.LocationURL <> "about:Tabs" And IE.LocationURL <> "about:blank" Then

                Dim HTMLDoc As mshtml.HTMLDocument
                HTMLDoc = IE.Document

                Dim iHTMLCol As IHTMLElementCollection
                Dim iHTMLEle As IHTMLElement
                Dim strId As String

                iHTMLCol = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("textarea")

                'Put the text into the TextArea
                For Each iHTMLEle In iHTMLCol
                    If Not iHTMLEle.getAttribute("id") Is Nothing Then
                        strId = iHTMLEle.getAttribute("id").ToString
                        If strId = "NAME OF YOUR FIELD" Then
                            iHTMLEle.setAttribute("value", "YOUR TEXT RIGHT HERE")
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```